# Como pasar el valor asignado a una variable de un .sql a un .bat que lo llamo

Tags: oracle

Tengo un .bat que manda ejecutar un .sql en cmd, en el .sql en base al resultado de un SELECT COUNT le asigno un valor a la variable starFlag. Como puedo pasar el resultado de esa variable al .bat que lo mando llamar, dado que con el valor recibido, se ejecutaran acciones en base a ese valor. De antemano gracias por el apoyo.

```
Este es el .bat:
@echo off
REM >>>En esta variable es donde recibiria el valor asignado en el .sql
SET starFlag= ' '
REM <<<
sqlplus SYSTEM/SYSTEM @C:\ScriptTst\ParaForo\FOROUPDATESKU.sql l> outputUPD.txt
IF %errorlevel% == 0 (  
    ECHO %TIME% El proceso de update inicio...
    SET errorlog= "Proceso UPDATESKU con exito" 
) ELSE (
    SET errorlog = 'Proceso UPDATESKU con error'
    ECHO Error number: %ERRORLEVEL%
    GOTO FIN_ERROR
)
GOTO TERMINABATCH
:FIN_ERROR
EXIT /b 1
:TERMINABATCH

Este es el .sql:
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    ResulCons NUMBER;
    starFlag VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ResulCons FROM SKURESP230711 WHERE ITEM = 'GALLETAS554' AND LOC = 'PAS4';
IF ResulCons > 0 THEN 
    -- >>> Esta variable (starFlag) la ocupo pasar al .bat que llamo este .sql 
    starFlag := 'UPDATESKU actualizo';
    -- <<< 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('starFlag:' || starFlag);
    UPDATE SKURESP230711 SET CREATIONDATE = to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YY') WHERE ITEM = 'GALLETAS554' AND LOC = 'PAS4';
ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ResulCons:' || ResulCons);
    starFlag := 'UPDATESKU inserto';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('starFlag:' || starFlag);
    INSERT INTO SKURESP230711 (ITEM, LOC, CREATIONDATE) VALUES ('GALLETAS554','PAS4',To_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'));
END IF;
COMMIT;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATESKU completado.');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATESKU con error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
DISCONNECT;
EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
```